# Would the quantum state of a photon be disturbed if it were traveling through fiber optic cabling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, fiber-optics

See here...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_optical_quantum_computing
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber_cable

I'm just worried that upon reflection within the cable the photon's quantum state would be disturbed. If it isn't disturbed then quantum transmission (implying quantum cryptography) would be realistically possible.

Comment: Fiber optics doesn't change the energy, it maintains coherence (over suitably short distances) and it should maintain (circular) polarization, not sure about the sensitivity to movement and twisting, though, so the answer to the feasibility of QC is probably affirmative. I don't see why a suitable fiber optical setup couldn't work. Quantum cryptography is done over fiber, so it's not a problem for that.

Comment: (1) There are no "reflections" in single-mode fibres, the model of a light beam simply breaks down at those scales. (2) The circular polarization components will acquire a geometrical phase (this causes linear polarization to be tilted).

Comment: So, do you need to use single-mode fiber for carrying photons without disturbing their quantum state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, no. [Optical fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber) do not disturb *much* the quantum state of photons, and are indeed routinely used for the implementation of quantum information and quantum communication protocols. Some major implementations of quantum key distribution networks are listed in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_key_distribution#Quantum_Key_Distribution_Networks).

Some types of fibers rotate the polarization of the light, or induce a [polarization dispersion factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_mode_dispersion), which can be an issue in several applications.
[Polarization-mantaining fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization-maintaining_optical_fiber) however exist and are used in the cases where preserving the polarization is essential (it's still worth noting that care must be taken over how the fibers are handled: even a small twisting of a fiber can result in a rotation of the polarization).

On the other hand, dispersion and loss are in some measure inevitable, and this limits how far can we make photons travel coherently.
For a review of these problematics a very nice read is the recent [Gisin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Gisin)'s paper: [How far can one send a photon?](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11467-015-0485-x) (arXiv [1508.00351](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00351)). He concludes that, considering the several relevant factors, the limit for direct quantum communication (over optical fiber channels) is 500 km, which is not possible with state of the art technology, but can be conceivably achieved in the near future.
Larger distances can be (conceivably) covered using [quantum repeaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_network#Quantum_repeaters).

Comment: Many thanks! Well cited and informative! Thank you once again!